Maximum allowed current sink for an Output low GPIO, and the 3.3v pinouts
I'm using a TXB10x level shifter to translate 3.3 GPIOs to 5V. I plan on supplying the 5V from a DCDC power converter to the peripherals, including the RPI, and the 3.3 V I plan on sourcing from the 3.3 supply pins of the RPI, as not much current is needed in the 3.3v range.
TI datasheets and online explanations on this translator note two things:

Some current (on the order of a few uA) will flow from the high side voltage supply (5V) into the low side voltage supply (3.3V). A few resistors will be placed along the way, with at least 200KOhm between the two sources.
Some current will flow into the transmitter GPIOs when they are set as output, low.

We plan on setting all GPIOs to push-pull, no open-drain configuration will be used.
In my case, the transmitter GPIOs are the RPI GPIOs serving as the MOSI, CLK, CS, and Reset lines, and the RPI 3.3V output pins.
I've ran an experiment using a very accurate DC power supply, and got these results for actual current sink on RPI GPIOs:

I can't say I understand how I got the -20mA current when GPIO 37 was in the Input, highZ state, but lets ignore that for a moment.
On a RPI zero 2W, how much current can the 3.3v output sink due to a higher voltage connected to it, and how much current can the GPIOs sink when they are set in the output direction, and outputting a low logic level?

You said, "I plan on supplying the 5V from a DCDC power converter to the peripherals, including the RPI, and the 3.3 V I plan on sourcing from the 3.3 supply pins of the RPI, as not much current is needed in the 3.3v range."  I'm sure this sentence makes sense to you, but it's confusing to me. I think you mean that you've decided to source the 5V to bias your level shifter from an external supply - correct? If so, can I ask why you decided to use a separate supply rather than take 5V from one of the RPi header pins?

Ideally you should use the 5V supply that the 5V device uses. They are logic level converters and will NOT provide any power.

The demands of the system in the 5V range are greater than what the RPI is able to supply. This is why we've designed it so that all of the system 5V devices are supplied directly from the DCDC converter (converts battery voltage to 5V). The RPI 5V input, the level shifter 5V input etc, are all sourced from a DCDC converter.
The system 3.3v current demands are quite low, and so the 3.3v RPI output is sufficient to run smoothly, which saves us the use of another DCDC converter.
